# R: plot variables, where the values are based on number of rows for specific combination

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a question I can't really get my head around. So maybe, if my explanation of the question is too vague, please don't hesitate to ask a question to clarify myself more.

I have a tibble in R of 3000+ observations (referrals) of general practitioners [GP] (see example for a subset of the data).
I would like to plot the data, for example using ggplot. Say I would like to plot how often a GP has referred in total (that would be number of rows for that particular name), how would I do that? 
Another column in the tibble consist of names of institutions they referred to. Say I want to plot how often they referred to a specific institution. The values would correspond to the number of rows for that particular combination, am I right? Does anybody know a way to do this?

Example data:

```
structure(list(LAST_NAME_GP = c("NOORDHOF", "ONBEKEND", "RAHIMTOOLA", 
"HIEMSTRA", "VIS", "OLDENBURG", "SLACHTER", "NOORDHOF", "VOSKUILEN", 
"STEVENS", "COMANS", "HIJMERING", "PHILIPS", "VIS", "LOUTER"), 
    INSTITUTION = c("OPVOEDPOLI B.V.", "PARLAN", "PARLAN", "PARLAN", 
    "OPVOEDPOLI B.V.", "TRIVERSUM", "ALKMAARSE PSYCHOLOGENPRAKTIJK", 
    "TRIVERSUM", "STICHTING KRAM", "TRIVERSUM", "TRIVERSUM", 
    "TRIVERSUM", "OPVOEDPOLI B.V.", "TRIVERSUM", "ELINE BIESHEUVEL"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

sample
# A tibble: 15 x 2
   LAST_NAME_GP  INSTITUTION                 
   <chr>         <chr>                     
 1 NOORDHOF      OPVOEDPOLI B.V.           
 2 ONBEKEND      PARLAN                    
 3 RAHIMTOOLA    PARLAN                    
 4 HIEMSTRA      PARLAN                    
 5 VIS           OPVOEDPOLI B.V.           
 6 OLDENBURG     TRIVERSUM                 
 7 SLACHTER      ALKMAARSE PSYCHOLOGENPRAK~
 8 NOORDHOF      TRIVERSUM                 
 9 VOSKUILEN     STICHTING KRAM            
10 STEVENS       TRIVERSUM                 
11 COMANS        TRIVERSUM                 
12 HIJMERING     TRIVERSUM                 
13 PHILIPS       OPVOEDPOLI B.V.           
14 VIS           TRIVERSUM                 
15 LOUTER        ELINE BIESHEUVEL
```

Please note: In my example data GPs maybe occur twice, but in the actual dataset they occur say 200 times.

Comment: What type of plot are you thinking? Bar charts, stacked bars, dot chart, heatmap...?

Comment: The values could correspond to the number of rows (counts) or percentages (given a GP, share of assignments to institution X or vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ggplot` histogram for the first part of your problem. Since you want to *plot how often a GP has referred in total*, a bar plot seems to be a quick solution:

```
ggplot(data=sample, aes(x=LAST_NAME_GP))+geom_bar()
```

Returns a histogram that indicate how often a GP has referred in total.

For the second part of your question, in trying to visualize how often a GP has referred to a specific institution, you can use `facet_wrap`, which present that information nicely without the risk of overplotting.

To use `facet_wrap` to display the values of both `LAST_NAME_GP` and `INSTITUTION` to great effect:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
sample %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=INSTITUTION))+
  geom_bar()+
  facet_wrap(~LAST_NAME_GP)+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: The first part shouldn't be a histogram, since that's intended for the distribution of *continuous* values broken into bins. This should be a bar chart of counts, as done by `geom_bar`

Comment: You are of course right @camille, aesthetically they are the same but yes histogram should be reserved for the distribution of continuous values and not discrete. Changed `geom_histogram()` to `geom_bar()`